# How to prevent tab item selection change event?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I am working on a wpf .My requirement is to change selection of tab  according to user confirmation it means every time when user changes tab a message box opens and confirm with user whether he wants to change the tab or not.

But problem with me is when I press no first time it works fine .but after that on second time  it asks two times for user confirmation

can anyone help me to solve this ?

```
private void tabcontrol_SelectionChanged(object sender,SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
    if (handleSelection  && e.OriginalSource == tbUserProfileMainControl)
        {
         //Ask user for change

         if (isUserAllowedToChanged)
             {
             int currentIndex = (tabcontrol.SelectedIndex);

             GeneralDeclaration.currentSelectedTabIndex = currentIndex;

             LoadUserControl(GeneralDeclaration.currentSelectedTabIndex);
             }
         else
             {
             //e.Handled = true;
             handleSelection = false;
             tbUserProfileMainControl.SelectedIndex = Math.Abs(tbUserProfileMainControl.SelectedIndex - 1);
              }
         }
   handleSelection = true;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
       {
        //
       }
}
```

Comment: I have to say that the first thing that strikes me is that this is an appalling UX design, second thing, please post your code. We can't help you if we can't see what you are doing. It's probably something simple that you'll get some great answers to if you post your code.

Comment: I have uploaded my code please check now

Comment: you are either adding event handlers along the way somehow and/or you are changing the tab from within the event handler...

Comment: @Abshishek Sheth: please edit your code, I failed to do it from mobile. It's hard to read.

Comment: If you do it a 3rd time, do you get 3 message boxes? And can you post how this event is hooked up to the TabControl?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're adding handlers during the click event itself. This causes your subsequent click to perform the action one more time (3rd click 3 times, 4th click 4 times, etc).

Check how you bind the event to the handler and check where you are defining the handler itself. You're doing something twice that should only be done once.

This is my estimation based on your findings, without code, I'm just taking a wild stab in the dark.

Comment: no I have checked again its associated from design only and once

Comment: @Abshishek Sheth: if you put a `brekpoint` in  the event handler, what call stack you see?